# AngularJS .success method and .then method

Tags: angularjs

Hi I need help with Angular JS
instead of using .success and .error how can I build this code using .then and .catch? I guess simply changing .success and .error to .then and .catch doesn't work.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
 $scope.formData = {};
 $http.get('/api/work')
 .success(function(data) {
 $scope.tasks = data;
 })
 .error(function(data) {
 console.log('Error: ' + data);
 });
});
```

Comment: `.then(successCallback).catch(errorCallback)`

Answer (score 1):

The angular api for this changed quite a long time.

Right now you should replace:

```
$http.get('/api/work')
    .success(function(data) {
        $scope.tasks = data;
    })
    .error(function(data) {
        console.log('Error: ' + data);
    });
```

to this

```
$http.get('/api/work')
    .then(function(response) {
        $scope.tasks = response.data;
    }, function(data) {
        console.log('Error: ' + data);
    });
```

because "then" works like this:

```
.then(successCallback, errorCallback, notifyCallback)
```

Comment: Not quite... The entire *response* object is passed to the `then()` callback, not just the data. It should be `.then(response => $scope.tasks = response.data)`

Comment: Phil is quite right, I copy paste your code without realizing that, already update my answer according to his suggestion

Comment: It's the same for the error state / `catch` callback as well

Answer (score -1):

In order to use "then" I believe you must use a Promise. Take a look here [Angular Promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

Comment: The `$http` service returns promises that are resolved / rejected with the HTTP `response` object. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: I've always wondered why people post comments instead of answers.  Now I know.  Thanks for the education.